# Lower bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, types

I have been trying to understand the concept and rationale behind the lower bounded wildcard in Java Generics. I can understand the reasoning behind the upper bounded wildcard being read only and where and how it can be used. I am still not able to get a grasp of the lower bounded wildcard. I have a set of classes which follow the below hierarchy. (`Automobile` is the base class.)

```
Automobile
    - Bus
        - Minibus
        - Doubledecker
        - Electricbus
    - Car
        - Sedan
        - Hatchback
        - Coupe
    - Truck
        - Minivan
        - Pickuptruck
        - Suv
            - Fullsuv
            - Midsuv
```

Now I am trying to build a (flexible) list and add objects of different types to it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Garage {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<? super Suv> list = null;

        Suv s = new Suv();
        Truck t = new Truck();
        Automobile a = new Automobile();

        list = new ArrayList<Suv>();
        list.add(s); // declared as List<? super Suv> but actually List<Suv>. No compilation error

        list = new ArrayList<Truck>();
        list.add(t); // declared as List<? super Suv> but actually List<Truck>. Compilation error

        list = new ArrayList<Automobile>();
        list.add(a); // declared as List<? super Suv> but actually List<Automobile>. Compilation error
    }
}
```

I am able to add an instance of `Suv` to `List<? super Suv>`. But I get compilation error when I try to add instances of `Truck` or `Automobile` to the same list. Isn't the `List<? super Suv>` flexible enough to take any instances of `Suv` or its super classes? `Truck` and `Automobile` are higher up in the hierarchy tree. Why am I not able to add instances of these to the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<? super Suv>` should be read as *"A list whose element type is a super type of `Suv`"*.

Now, let's look at these two lines:

```
list = new ArrayList<Automobile>();
list.add(a); // where a is an Automobile
```

The first line is ok, since `ArrayList<Automobile>` is indeed *"a list whose element type is a super type of `Suv`"*.

But let's read out the second line: Add some `Automobile` to a list whose element type is as super type of `Suv`.

As far as the compiler knows from the static types,

- `list` could refer to a `List<Truck>` (since `Truck` is a super type of `Suv`) and
- `t` may refer to a `Car` (since a `Car` is an `Automobile`)

So the compiler complains to make sure you're not adding a `Car` to a list of `Trucks`.

---

Useful reading:

- [Java Generics: extends, super and wildcards explained](http://onewebsql.com/blog/generics-extends-super) (section *When to use extends and super*)

Comment: This is the important distinction: the compiler only knows the *declared*, wildcard type of `list`, not the actual instantiated type. It can't perform the necessary analysis to find the real type when that line runs, partly because it's not practical, but also because the JLS just doesn't allow it.

Comment: @aioobe So if I want to add instances of a Truck or an Automobile to a list, would I have to declare specifically declared lists for them? 

List<? super Truck> listOfTrucks;
List<? super Automobiles> listOfAuto;

Suppose I have a method that takes a list of Suv or its super types : 
loadGarage(List<? super Suv listOfSuv). 

Since listOfSuvs takes only instances of Suv and complains when I add Truck or Automobile to it, should I have overloaded loadGarage methods to accept Truck and Automobile?
Like 

loadGarage(List<Truck> listOfTruck) 

and 

loadGarage(List<Automobile> listOfAutomobile)

Comment: From the link at the bottom of my answer: *"If you get something from a parametrized container, use extends. [...] if you put objects into a parametrized container, use super."* If your `loadGarage` method should put `Automobiles` in the provided list, you should let the method accept any list which can store `Automobiles`, i.e. `List<? super Automobile>`.